Searching for the name of an old animated series
I can't remember the name of an TV animated series I watched in the 80s.
It involved fighting with giant flying robots and ran about the same time as Transformers.
Here's what I remember (time may have corrupted my memories somewhat) :
In the first episode, a bald man go to fetch a boy from an airport, they are attacked by some evil henchmen. The man then defends himself by drawing a sort of lightsaber from his umbrella.
...Many episodes with flying robots combats.
In the last episode, the bald man is trying to shoot the main villain with a rocket launcher while the boy is being absorbed by some sort of computer.
All the action takes place on earth, there is no spaceships or aliens involved (that I remember).
The heroes fight with three flying ships that can combine to form a big robot. To fight bigger ennemies they call up a larger robot, the three ships are "inserted" into it to control it.
Does that ring any bells?

Robot cartoons were very popular in the 80's, I believe. You are talking about the US, right? Off the top of my head, could it be the Go Bots? Maybe Voltron?

There were only three human pilots in this show, and no talking/sentient robots.
